# Efficiently finding the value of a pixel in a Bitmap?

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, game-engine

So, I'm programming a game where you shoot bullets at enemies. I'm currently designing the hit detection method, which involves each bullet and enemy (which are themselves complex shapes drawn using Paths) getting their own scaled-down Bitmap (bulletMask[] and enemyMask[]), using the ALPHA_8 configuration where 0 alpha means nothing is there, and 255 alpha means there is something there.

The Bitmaps are all being drawn fine and the drawing operations perform fine. However, when I need to run a check on which bullets are intersecting which enemies, I get HUGE lag, on the order of 300-400 milliseconds. Now, the reason for this is because I'm taking a brute-force method to detecting hits. Here's the loop that's involved:

```
    for (int y = 0; y < height / 8; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width / 8; x++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ENEMIES; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < MAX_BULLETS; j++) {
                    if (bulletMask[j].getPixel(x, y) != 0 && enemyMask[i].getPixel(x, y) != 0) {
                        enemy[ALIVE][i] = 0;
                        bullet[ALIVE][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically, it goes through each pixel, and checks if any enemy pixels are intersecting any bullet pixels. If they are, both the bullet and the pixel go away.

MAX_ENEMIES is 10 and MAX_BULLETS is 5, while the number of pixels in each Bitmap is 32400, meaning that this loop must repeat 1.62 million times per frame. I have not yet begun to code anything beyond this brute-force algorithm, but I have a feeling I'll need to design something more complex if I can't find a solution.

I simply need a more efficient way of finding pixels, or at least comparing pixels between Bitmaps. Editing out the if block in the code above makes the game run fine.

Comment: check collision/hit detection in existing physic engines, u could give a whole lecture on this topic

Comment: I've looked through a whole bunch of stuff, but I'm not utilizing OpenGL and there's not much information on basic hit detection using complex shapes like what I'm trying to do. I've been looking for an easy way out for a week or two, and some sort of brute force is all I've really been able to come up with.

Comment: Could you imagine a hitbox or many hitboxes on the object, and then check for collision then by pixels

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing. I'm taking each object, drawing each onto its own Bitmap that is scaled down x8 (this is the hitbox, shaped exactly like the real object but pixelated), and checking for collisions.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question. Check this answer http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/13117 and http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30866/collision-detection-with-non-rectangular-images/30870#30870

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the position of each bullet and enemy, you can use a mathematical approach, removing the need for any pixel checks, by doing a radius test comparing the bullets with the enemies to see if they intersect.

For example, if the distance between the center of the bullet and the center of an enemy is less than sum of the radius of the two, that means there is a collision.

Or instead of a radius test, you can assign each a hit area rectangle, and check if the rectangles are intersecting.

If you need pixel perfect collisions, you can simply iterate over the pixels surrounding each bullet and checking if the enemies are in their area. Assuming the bullets have an area of 50 pixels, that means only checking 2500 pixels (at most) for all 5 bullets and 10 enemies.

You could even combine both methods, doing the radius/rectangle test as a preliminary check, and only if successful, looping through the pixels, though it might not be necessary.

You should also be breaking out of the loop once you know that an enemy is dead or if a bullet has been used up, instead of continuing with the calculations.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll probably implement a prediction filter like what you described at some point in the future. I didn't even think to break the loop.

Answer (score 3):

4 loops inside of each other are indeed bad. Looks like O(n²).

The first thing you might want to do is to convert your bitmaps to int-Arrays. If you are using BufferedImage, then there's `getRGB` for you.

Second, you should not brute-force it like that. Something like iterating over the bullets and then checking just the pixels they occupy will give you a huge performance boost.

Comment: Okay, wow, I don't know why I didn't think of it that way haha. Also, instead of using an int array, would it be (even just slightly) better to use a boolean array, since each pixel will only switch between two values? And won't converting my Bitmap into an array use  getPixel() anyway?

Comment: 1. Booleans need less resources, so of course you can use those. 2. Yes, but the other, [faster getPixel() function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)